# How to add scatter to figure over subplots?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, figure, subplot

I have a script for subplots and I added over subplot text and arrow (end of the script). How to add scatter? I tried:

```
scatter = fig.add_scatter(0.5, 0.5, marker = '_', s=300)
fig.add_scatter(0.5, 0.5, marker = '_', s=300)
```

The error is:
**'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_scatter'**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D                 # 3d graph
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d                 # 3d graph
from matplotlib.text import Text 
from matplotlib.patches import Arrow 

# Plot subplot 
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(10,13))

x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 5]
fig1 = plt.subplot(421)
plt.plot(x,y)

fig2 = plt.subplot(422)
plt.plot(x,y)

fig3 = plt.subplot(423, projection = '3d') # number of vertical figures, number of horizontal figures, order

# Plot figure with size
fig4=plt.subplot(424, projection = '3d')

fig5=plt.subplot(425, projection = '3d')

fig6=plt.subplot(426, projection = '3d')

fig7=plt.subplot(427, projection = '3d')

fig8=plt.subplot(428, projection = '3d')


text = fig.add_artist(Text(0.56,0.198, text='Hello'))

arrow = fig.add_artist(Arrow(0.52, 0.6, 0, -0.08, width=.02)) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

The desired result is to add scatter, for instance, between 3rd and 4th subplot.

Answer (score 0):

You may not understand the full intent of the question, but you can draw a scatter plot with the following code.

```
N=100
X = np.random.rand(N, 3)
y = np.random.rand(N) * 2 - 1
fig3.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1],zs=X[:, 2],zdir='z', s=50, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

Comment: Your script added scatter to the third figure but I am my question is about adding scatter wherever as the arrow and text 'Hello' in the script in my question.